# Synchronize a list of blocked websites between multiple computers

Tags: browser

So far, I've been using various web site blockers, but I haven't found any that can synchronize a list of blocked sites. Is there any way to synchronize a list of blocked websites between multiple computers (so that the websites cannot be accessed from any of the computers?)

Comment: You can get sync to work for any extension, by using dropbox or something like that and sync the folder where the extension store settings.

Comment: @Lamb Is it possible to use Dropbox to synchronize files that are outside the Dropbox folder?

Comment: Not officially, but it is possible with use of, Sync Toy provided by Microsoft, or by using symlinks, a [lifehacker article](http://m.lifehacker.com/5154698/sync-files-and-folders-outside-your-my-dropbox-folder).

Answer (score 1):

If your list of websites is just a list of domain names — you can set up your own DNS server somewhere and use that DNS for all your machines. For a server create a `hosts` file based on this list. It should look like

```
127.0.0.1 badsite.com
127.0.0.1 evilsite.org
```

DNS server software options depend on your OS. for linux you can try [dnsmasq](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html). You can even run it on your OpenWRT-compatible router.

Answer (score 0):

So far, the only browser extension that can do this (that I know of) is called StayFocusd (for Google Chrome). There may be other extensions with this feature as well, but I haven't found any others yet (after much searching).

Comment: I hope there are browser extensions for Firefox that can do this as well - I sometimes use Firefox as well as Chrome.